# How can I preview html file in another window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, preview

Hy,

In my application I store a html code in a string, for example:

```
string myHtml = "<html><body><input type ='text' value='hello'/></body></html>";
```

How can I preview this html in another window pressing some button?

```
 <asp:Button ID="PreviewButton" runat="server" Text="Preview" OnClick="PreviewButton_Click"/>
```

I've tried :

```
protected void PreviewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             myHtml = "<html><body><input type ='text' value='hello'/></body></html>";
             Response.Write(myHtml);
             Response.End();
         }
```

And it works, the preview it's opened but in the same window.. does anyone know how can I open it in another window?

Thanks in advance.

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the source in a javascript string and use window.open and then write to the new window the source.

Remeber to escape the source correctly first.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `window.open` in Javascript to open a new window showing an ASHX handler that serves your HTML. (you may need to pass information on the query string)
Remember to set the `Response.ContentType` in the handler.

Comment: @Richard: Why? If you don't need to overhead of ASPX, don't use it.

Comment: I've tried this too, but javascript does not recognise the < > and gives errors...

Comment: @Jeff: Then that's not what you tried.  `window.open('/MyHandler.ashx')`.

Comment: @SLaks: My rationale is that using an aspx page would be simpler, and that the overhead concerned is negligible.

Comment: @Richard: How would it be simpler?

Comment: @Jeff: You need a separate URL for the new window.  That separate URL might as well be an ASHX rather than an ASPX.

Comment: I've tried now : 
            Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
            Response.Write("<script>");
            Response.Write("window.open('" + myHtml+"')");
            Response.Write("</script>");
            Response.End();

Comment: @Jeff: You're totally misunderstanding this.  Call `window.open` in Javascript in the original page instead of running server-side code.  Pass it a **URL** that points to an ASHX handler that writes your HTML.

Comment: @SLaks: For me, it comes down to consistent use of WebForms. The "usual" mechanism for rendering a web page in WebForms is via an ASPX file. To stray from that adds complexity.